# Javascript closure not working with google maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Would somebody please advise me as to what I'm doing wrong with this piece of code?

I am currently using a simple JSON file to provide data for info windows using the Google maps V3 API. I am aware of the concept of closures but cannot seem to understand why the info windows are still displaying the last result on click.

Here is my JSON file:

```
{ "markers": [
{
"lat": 51.5001524,
"lng": -0.1262362,
"firstName": "nameOne"
},
{
"lat": 55.8656274,
"lng": -4.2572227,
"firstName": "nameTwo"
},
{
"lat": 43.834526782236814,
"lng": -37.265625,
"firstName": "nameThree"
}
] }
```

**Here is my JS:**

```
(function(){

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5001524, -0.1262362)

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 3,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

    function parseJson(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/js/markers.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                processMarkers(data)
            }, 
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('fail')
            }
        })
    }

      function processMarkers(data){

        var totalMarkers = data.markers.length;
        for(i=0;i<totalMarkers;i++){
            var latitude = data.markers[i].lat;
            var longditude = data.markers[i].lng;
            var putMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longditude);
            var thisMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: putMarker,
                  map: map
                });

            var firstName = data.markers[i].firstName;
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                position: putMarker,
                content: firstName
            });

            new google.maps.event.addListener(
                thisMarker, 
                'click', 
                buildHandler(map, thisMarker));
        }

        function buildHandler(map, marker){
            return function(){
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            };
        }

    }

    parseJson();

  }

$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});
})();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I don't see anything in there about "click" handling.

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by moving the infoWindow and event creation to another function and passing each new marker to that function. You can take a look at my code here: http://ipreferjim.com/maps/main.js

Answer (score 1):

infoWindow is some var in the processMarkers scope.  That iterates over the same infoWindow over and over for every marker, orphaning it after the last iteration (and leaving it set to the final marker).  The orphan cannot die because it's captured in the closure of your click handler.  I do not know the google api well enough to predict what's supposed to happen on .open().  But infoWindow doesn't look good at that point...

EDIT:  In fact, it seems to me that every infoWindow but the last falls victim to the garbage collector.  Or is it referenced somewhere?  I cannot make it out.

EDIT:  Remember, JS does NOT have {} scopes (like eg C).  It only has functional scopes !!  In other words, simply pass infoWndow into your buildHandler().